# how to inject factory to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a function in a factory and trying to inject in the controller. But I am getting an error saying, unknown provider. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
app.factory('pdfdwn', function($scope) {
return{
download:function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('export'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
    var docDefinition = {
      content: [{
          image: data, 
          width: 500,          
      }]
    };
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Table.pdf");
    }
    });
      return download();
    }
    }
});
```

controller:

```
    app.controller('myctrl', function($scope,pdfdwn){
     $scope.pdf = function() {
       var pdd = pdfdwn.download();
   };
});
```

Comment: You can't inject `$scope` into an factory.. what you are looking for is a directive.

Comment: may be you have not added the `directive` js file in the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.remove $scope from factory method because you cannot inject inside.

2.Remove the `return download();` from the factory, because u are already returning the download.

Inside the controller:

```
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope,pdfdwn){
  $scope.pdf = function() {
     pdfdwn.download();
   };
});
```